Tagging Products from "Apple Store" in YouTube Shorts
I’m trying to tag an app from the Apple Store as a product in my YouTube videos/shorts so that viewers are immediately directed to the app store when they click on it (similar to this example video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/VXggN9VcnAM).
However, I haven’t been able to do this using any of the stores available on YouTube (Fourthwall, Shopify, Spreadshop, or Spring). None of these options provide a direct link to the App Store like in the video example I provided.
Could anyone please guide me on how to replicate what the creator in the sample video did to link directly to the apps in the App Store? Thank you!


I'm trying to tag an app from the Apple Store as a product
in my YouTube videos/shorts so that viewers are immediately directed
to the app store when they click on it (similar to this example
video: ...

Viewers are not immediately directed to the app store from that video.  

However, I haven’t been able to do this using any of the
stores available on YouTube (Fourthwall, Shopify, Spreadshop, or
Spring). None of these options provide a direct link to the App Store
like in the video example I provided.

The video does not provide a direct link to the App Store.  

Could anyone please guide me on how to replicate what the creator in the sample video did to link directly to the apps in the App Store?

These are the steps to replicate it.

Create a Shopify store
Create a store product for your mobile app.
Tag your product in a YouTube video.
Identify store visitors' mobile platform.
Redirect users to your App Store (IOS) or Play Store (Android) download page.

